# How do I test an interface that has no implementation

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I have an interface and its implementation. I'm working on a plugin for JIRA. I've just decided on its design but do not have implementation as such. I'm kinda lost on how to test it when it has no methods in it. Can anyone pls help? thanks..

```
package com.cerner.jira.plugins.esig.servicemanager;

import java.util.List;

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.cerner.jira.plugins.esig.issuetab.*;

public interface EsignatureManager {

    public List<EsignatureTabPanelData> getElectronicSignatures(Issue paramIssue);

}
```

and I have a class that implements this...

```
package com.cerner.jira.plugins.esig.

import java.util.List;
import com.cerner.jira.plugins.esig.customfields.UnameCustomField;

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.cerner.jira.plugins.esig.issuetab.EsignatureTabPanelData;

public class EsignatureManagerImpl implements EsignatureManager {

    UnameCustomField unamecustomfield;

    @Override 
    public List<EsignatureTabPanelData> getElectronicSignatures(Issue paramIssue) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to test? The empty implementation? Why bother?

Comment: EsignatureManager has a method (getElectronicSignatures), I do not understand why you say it has no methods?

Comment: Are you doing TDD? if so write a test that expects your method to return a non-empty list of that type. if not write your implementation then write your test accordingly.

Comment: you can just write test skeleton as you have written your design skeleton. In real nothing to test as nothing has implemented. But as you move forward with implementation, you can keep updating your test skeleton as well with some meaningful tests.

Comment: I meant it just returns null for now.. I haven't actually written anything for it.. and I know its gonna fail cos it has nothing. But is there a way to mock this class? that's what I'm looking at.

Answer (score 1):

An interface cannot be tested as well as if it compiles it makes all the functions that it should do. You can't test something that do nothing, that is the case of an interface.

Answer (score 1):

Test the class that implements the interface.  If you are doing test driven development, write the test to look for what you expect your getElectroniceSignatures to return, possibly a non-empty list of the type you specified?  If you are not, then go ahead and implement the interface member in the class first, then write a test method for the classes implementation of the interface member once you have it doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could start it off with something like this and change your test as you know more about your methods.

```
@Test
public void getElectronicSignatures(){
    fail("Not implemented yet");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is an answer to your specific (JIRA specific) use case, but: it is possible to test an interface: You can use reflection to check if the interface provides specific methods, annotation etc. (but I assume you meant "test" in the context of JIRA?).

Comment: Well, not exactly at this point.. Maybe after I start with the implementation of this skeleton, it will become Jira specific. now it doesn't matter